# Routing error? maybe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join

I keep getting this error when trying to view my channels controller.

> uninitialized constant
>   Channel::MessagesChannel

I'm gonna guess its a routing error but I have no idea how to fix it.

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages_channel , :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :channels, :through => :mesages_channels

  #joins between users and messages
  has_many :user_messages
  has_many :users, :through => :user_messages
end
```

.

```
class Channel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages_channels , :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :messages ,:through => :messages_channels
  has_many :channel_mods , :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :moderators , :class_name =>"User", :through => :channel_mods
  has_many :users_channels , :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :users, :through => :users_channels

end
```

.

```
class MessagesChannels < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :message
  belongs_to :channel
end
```

.

```
SeniorProject::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :users 

  resources :channels do
    resources :messages
  end

  resources :users, :user_sessions
  match 'login' => 'user_sessions#new', :as => :login
  match 'logout' => 'user_sessions#destroy', :as => :logout
  match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
  #match 'subscribe' =>'channels#subscribe', :as => :subscribe

  match 'subscribe/:channel_id/:user_id' =>'channels#subscribe', :as => :subscribe

  root :to => 'channels#index', :as => :listchannels



end
```

Comment: please post more details about the error message, what are you doing when it fails?

Comment: <span class="messages">(<%= pluralize(channel.messages.size, 'message') %>)</span>
Causes the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model **MessagesChannels** shouldn't be plural, but singular.

Comment: so go back and do " rails g migrations ChannelMessage " ? even though a channel will have several messages?

Comment: Lol I feel kinda stupid, i dont ever need this relationship is a many-to-one relationship. thanx for ya help though